# brute force only works on some passwords but not others no matter the difficulty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, brute-force

so i have this program im trying to make but here the thing. its trying to brute force a password in a string but the thing is it only gets some. for example this one handles up to 5 characters. if i put the password as gbdff it will crack easy but hello and it stops why is that? here is code.

````
index = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'

library = []

for i in index:
    library.append(i)

for i in range(len(index)):
    brute = str(library[i])
    if brute == password:
        print('Password is', brute)
    for w in range(0,i):
        brute = str(library[i] + library[w])
        if brute == password:
            print('Password is', brute)
        for x in range(0,i):
            brute = str(library[i] + library[w] + library[x])
            if brute == password:
                print('Password is', brute)
            for y in range(0,i):
                brute = str(library[i] + library[w] + library[x] + library[y])
                if brute == password:
                    print('Password is', brute)
                for z in range(0,i):
                    brute = str(library[i] + library[w] + library[x] + library[y] + library[z])
                    if brute == password:
                        print('Password is', brute)```
````

Comment: You’re only checking letters that have an index less than the first letter. You will only ever match inputs where all chars are “before” the first letter

Comment: so how do i fix that? can you show me some code?

Comment: Not to your question, just a general thought: this script might benefit from using recursion. Also, there's no need to have ```for i in index: library.append(i)```. You could instead simply do ```library = list(index)```.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using all of the nested for loops, you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all possible combinations of input

```
itertools.product(index, repeat=len(password))
```

This will return a generator that produces tuples the same length as the password so we can then use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert them to strings

```
map(''.join, itertools.product(index, repeat=len(password)))
```

Then you can loop over this generator to find the result

```
for brute in map(''.join, itertools.product(index, repeat=len(password))):
    if brute == password:
        print('Password is', brute)
        break
```

EDIT:

The docs for itertools.product give an example of an equivalent method if you must not import anything. You will have to tailor this to your needs

> This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do that without using imports

Comment: Using recursion, the only way

Comment: @TechySavage there is an example in the docs for an equivalent function. Pasted into the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to try all combinations of letters up to a certain length (5). Instead of nesting for loops, I would use recursion like this:

```py
index = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890')

def recurse(max_depth, dep=1, cur=''):
  if (cur == "hel"): # win condition
    print("Password: " + cur)
    return True;
  for c in index: # for every character on this "layer"
    if (dep < max_depth): # don't exceed max depth
      if recurse(max_depth, dep+1, cur+c):
        return True # break out of recursive stack
recurse(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to my question is to fix this.
Replace `For w in range(0,i):` with `For W in range(0,len(library)) :`

That will get it to go up in order.